# Laravel mail queue subject not being applied

Tags: php, laravel

I always have lots of problems with Mail::queue and this time the subject is not being applied properly.

This is my class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class PlanExpiringOrExpired extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $payment = null;


    public function __construct($payment)
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;
        $this->subject($this->payment->subject);

        \Log::debug("Subject: {$this->payment->subject}");
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $this->to($this->payment->email, $this->payment->name)
            ->view('mails/payment')
            ->with('payment', $this->payment);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And I call it this way:

```
$payment = \App\Models\Payments::findOrFail($id);
$payment->subject = 'Your account has been canceled';

\Mail::queue(new \App\Mail\PlanExpiringOrExpired($payment));
```

The `log` saved **correctly** the following content:

```
[2023-02-12 11:00:04] local.DEBUG: Subject: Your account has been canceled
```

Yet the user received as subject: `Plan Expiring or Expired` (which is basically the class name).

Since I've done this change recently, do you think this might be a cache-related problem? If so, I'm using Supervisor to run queues, how do I clear the cache (through PHP) without messing up the production server?

I have used in the past something like this.

```
\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct, or if it has any implications for my production server.

Comment: Have you restarted the Queue?

Comment: So basically I need to restart the queue whenever I perform any changes in the `Mail` classes? I just executed `cache:clear` & `queue:restart`. I can't test it right now, but in the following days I'll see if it's working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

It was indeed a cache problem, it is also necessary to restart the queue. My solution was to create a private endpoint like `/superadmin/clear-cache` and use it whenever I need.

```
Route::get('/superadmin/clear-cache', function()
{
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    \Artisan::call('queue:restart');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way to setup the proper subject?

```
private $payment = null;

public function __construct($payment)
{
    $this->payment = $payment;
}

public function build()
{
    $this->to($this->payment->email, $this->payment->name)
        ->subject($this->payment->subject)
        ->view('mails/payment')
        ->with('payment', $this->payment);

    \Log::debug("Subject: {$this->payment->subject}");

    return $this;
}
```

Move the `subject` set into `build`

Comment: Yes. I always had the variables set in the `build` function, but because recently I had a problem with `from->()`, I switched to the `__construct` and since it started working, I decided to set some variables in the `__construct`, one of them was the subject. I think it's a cache issue..

Answer (score 0):

iam doing like this in queue class, EmailContactForm is a mailable class.

```
    public function handle()
{
    $email = new EmailContactForm([
        'locale' => $this->data['locale'],
        'from_email' => $this->data['from_email'],
        'name' => $this->data['name'],
        'topic' => $this->data['topic'],
        'subject' => $this->data['subject'],
        'msg' => $this->data['msg']
    ]);

    Mail::to($this->data['to_email'])
        ->bcc(config('app.mail_from_address'))
        ->send($email);
}
```